# How to pull value from a column when several columns match in two data frames?

Tags: python, match, where-clause

I am trying to write a script which will search a database similar to that in Table 1 based on a product/region/year specification outlined in table 2. The plan is to search for a match in Table 1 to a specification outlined in Table 2 and then pull the observation value, as seen in Table 2 - with results.

I need this code to run several loops, where the year criteria is relaxed. For example, loop 1 would search for a match in Product_L1, Geography_L1 and Year and loop 2 would search for a match in  Product_L1, Geography_L1 and Year-1 and so on.

Table 1

| Product level 1 | Product level 2 | Region level 1 | Region level 2 | Year | Obs. value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Portland cement | Cement | Peru | South America | 2021 | 1 |
| Portland cement | Cement | Switzerland | Europe | 2021 | 2 |
| Portland cement | Cement | USA | North America | 2021 | 3 |
| Portland cement | Cement | Brazil | South America | 2021 | 4 |
| Portland cement | Cement | South Africa | Africa | 2021 | 5 |
| Portland cement | Cement | India | Asia | 2021 | 6 |
| Portland cement | Cement | Brazil | South America | 2020 | 7 |

Table 2

| Product level 1 | Product level 2 | Region level 1 | Region level 2 | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Portland cement | Cement | Brazil | South America | 2021 |
| Portland cement | Cement | Switzerland | Europe | 2021 |

Table 2 - with results

| Product level 1 | Product level 2 | Region level 1 | Region level 2 | Year | Loop 1 | Loop 2 | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Portland cement | Cement | Brazil | South America | 2021 | 4 | 7 |  |

I have tried using the following code, but it comes up with the error 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to prevent this error?

```
Table_2['Loop_1'] = np.where((Table_1.Product_L1 == Table_2.Product_L1)
                             & (Table_1.Geography_L1 == Table_2.Geography_L1)
                             & (Table_1.Year == Table_2.Year), 
                             Table_1(['obs_value'], ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a merge operation and provide a list of columns that you want from `Table_1`.

```
import pandas as pd

Table_1 = pd.DataFrame({
      "Product_L1":["Portland cement", "Portland cement", "Portland cement", "Portland cement", "Portland cement", "Portland cement", "Portland cement"],
      "Product_L2":["Cement", "Cement", "Cement", "Cement", "Cement", "Cement", "Cement"],
      "Geography_L1": ["Peru", "Switzerland", "USA", "Brazil", "South Africa", "India", "Brazil"],
      "Geography_L2": ["South America", "Europe", "North America", "South America", "Africa", "Asia", "South America"],
      "Year": [2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2020],
      "obs_value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    })

Table_2 = pd.DataFrame({
      "Product_L1":["Portland cement", "Portland cement"],
      "Product_L2":["Cement", "Cement"],
      "Geography_L1": ["Brazil", "Switzerland"],
      "Geography_L2": ["South America", "Europe"],
      "Year": [2021, 2021]
    })

columns_list = ['Product_L1','Product_L2','Geography_L1','Geography_L2','Year','obs_value']

result = pd.merge(Table_2, Table_1[columns_list], how='left')
```

`result` is a new dataframe:

```
        Product_L1 Product_L2 Geography_L1   Geography_L2  Year  obs_value
0  Portland cement     Cement       Brazil  South America  2021          4
1  Portland cement     Cement  Switzerland         Europe  2021          2
```

**EDIT:** Based upon the update to the question, I think what you are trying to do is achievable using [set_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html). This will create a new dataframe with the observed values listed in columns 'Year_2020', 'Year_2021' etc.

```
index_columns = ['Product_L1','Product_L2','Geography_L1','Geography_L2', 'Year']
edit_df = Table_1.set_index(index_columns)['obs_value'].unstack().add_prefix('Year_').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, that does solve the problem I initially posted, but this was a simplified version. I have now edited the question to outline how I need to relax the Year classification to estimate several loops, each resulting in a new column.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are not interested in the `year` column, but you want to add columns with the observed value for x preceding years e.g. [2021, 2020, 2019, etc.]